# Count in a lateral join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large table that looks like this (omitting columns for simplicity) -

```
rend        bill        to_rend      to_bill        
190131602   190131602   1386688992   131618 
190131602   13464238    1386688992   1316116
```

I am running this query to get different connections from this table -

```
select distinct v.npi1, v.npi2
from test cross join lateral
     (values (rend, bill), (rend, to_rend), (rend, to_bill), (bill, to_rend), 
     (bill, to_bill), (to_rend, to_bill)
     ) v(npi1, npi2)
     order by v.npi1, v.npi2
```

The result of this query is -

```
npi1        npi2 
190131602   190131602
190131602   1386688992
190131602   131618 
190131602   13464238
190131602   1316116
1386688992   131618
```

I have the following questions -

1. How do I add an additional column to the result that counts the number of occurrences a combination appeared?

For example -

```
npi1        npi2         count 
190131602   1386688992   1
190131602   131618       1
190131602   13464238     1
190131602   1316116      1
1386688992  131618       1
```

2. How do I stop npi1 and npi2 from having the same value (First record in the output)?
3. Is there a more optimized query to achieve what I am looking for? The table this query is going to run on has millions of records and I don't think this query is going to perform well on that amount of data.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: It's LATERAL _derived table_, not some kind of join. I.e. the LATERAL keyword belongs to the subquery after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want `group by`:

```
select v.npi1, v.npi2, count(*)
from test cross join lateral
     (values (rend, bill), (rend, to_rend), (rend, to_bill), (bill, to_rend), 
     (bill, to_bill), (to_rend, to_bill)
     ) v(npi1, npi2)
where npi1 <> npi2
group by v.npi1, v.npi2;
```